# Image segmentation of flora in the wild

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, image-processing, image-segmentation

Here is an image of jackfruit in the wild and I want to segment this.
[image: Jackfuit]

Finding the maximum contour results in the following image -

[image: Jackfruit max_contour]

Now, it's possible that I try some different parameters to get the perfect segmentation for this **particular** image. However, I have lots of different images of plants and fruits in the wild.

Therefore, I thought of adding another step to this, i.e. from this segmented image, I find the connected component and that would get me the whole fruit segmented.

I have tried the flood-fill algorithm but to no avail as the fruit itself has a range of pixel values.

Comment: I believe that such problems are more commonly solved with object detection (given whatever ML/non-ML approach you can apply based on size of your database) & with the object itself being cropped - you may find it much easier to find contours because usually contrast with background would be higher (compared to trying to find contours on full image)

Comment: I want to keep ML as the last approach because it's expensive (data labeling boxes). The end objective is classification and therefore, if this segmentation could be worked out then it's a good feature for classifiers.

Comment: Are you trying to segment only this image or to find a more generic solution for the whole dataset?

Comment: A generic solution for the whole dataset. Also, this is one of the best images in the dataset in terms of object being in the foreground and it being clearly distinguishable.

Comment: If you think the images vary a lot, just as an idea, would you think about a half automatic segmentation? Like, you spot a few pixels on the object, and detect the object by using those pixel values?

Comment: I would love if that is possible. I had the same idea with the flood-fill algorithm, i.e., use this maximum contour to kind of get the object, anything other than blue becomes the pixels for the object and I would then kinda get the object through that. Obviously the last step didn't work.